# When I use a transparent theme a panel becomes visible. How do I remove it?

Tags: gnome, themes

Under my system taskbar, there is a panel showing. How do I remove it?

When I use a transparent theme the panel becomes visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a known bug. There are two main ways to solve it, choose the one that you prefere:

1. in gnome-tweak-tool disability the handling of the desktop by file manager
2. remove all the packages related to appmenu.

Comment: I have the same bug, do you have the launchpad bug number please?

Comment: No, I'm sorry. I now use Gnome-Shell and the problem is gone.